# How to reopen the existing tab on mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, html

On PC browser, we can easily use:

`window.open('my_url','target_name').focus()`

Or:

`<a href='my_url' target='target_name'>describe</a>`

to reopen or focus the existing tab.

But when it comes to mobile browser, none of these methods work. How can I make it work on a mobile browser?

Comment: okay, I'm here to tell you my solution.Before you open the tab, close the previous one.Just that simple.Any other solution is welcome.